# How can i switch on LED on STM32F1 GPIO pin PA2?

Tags: stm32

How can i switch on the LED on PA2 GPIO (STM32F103C8T6), using standard registry configuration.

```
RCC-> APB2ENR |= (1<<2);
GPIOA->CRL |= (1<<9);
GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<3);
```

Does not work for me. Could you please advice where i make mistake?

Comment: The first one : magic numbers

Comment: I did not get, what you mean.

Comment: Use CMSIS human readable definitions.  You make less mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the reference manual, the GPIOA CRL registers resets as 0x4444 4444 (See section 9.2.1 of the reference manual). 
When you execute the following command:

```
GPIOA->CRL |= (1<<9);
```

you are setting the MODE bits of PA2 to 10 (Output mode, max speed 2 MHz). But due to the inital register initialization, the CNF2 bits are 01, which is open-drain configuration. You should initialize PA2 with the following instead

```
GPIOA->CRL &= ~(0b0000<<8);
GPIOA->CRL |= (0b0010<<8);
```

This ensures that both MODE2 and CNF2 are both set so the pin acts as an output with a push-pull configuration

Comment: Also, for PA2 you need `GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<2);`. I prefer to use `BSRR` register most of the time.