# Can not blink the LED PA5 on Nucleo board

Tags: stm32, nucleo

Could you please help me to identify where i make the mistake? LED is on PA5 port.

```
int main(void){
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    while(1){
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
        HAL_Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Nucleo board? specifically which MCU?

Comment: BTW, is this related to your earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920888/how-can-i-switch-on-led-on-stm32f1-gpio-pin-pa2?

Comment: Board is : Nucleo L073RZ

Answer (score 0):

On microcontrollers pins have multiple functions, which functions is enabled has to be configured by software and sometimes by hardware (pulling pins to VCC or GND,...). `PA5` of the STM32L073xZ has alternate functions, this is in the datasheet (https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/389/stm32l073v8-956245.pdf) on page 39 and 45, the package of the MCU on the Nucleo L073RZ is LQFP64, cf schematic of the Nucleo in https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf on page 64 (https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/2f/b9/c6/34/28/29/42/d2/DM00095744.pdf/files/DM00095744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00095744.pdf).

i do not know if you have enabled the alternate functions somewhere in the rest of your code however this is possibly the core of the problem. The part of the code you posted is accurate, in https://github.com/TechBreiteneder/00_GPIO_BlinkLED/blob/master/Src/main.c is LED blinking code in a CubeMX project. So possibly you enabled an alternate function on pin PA5, in addition you have to enable other components like the clock system for the MCU to work at all, cf https://riptutorial.com/stm32/example/25059/first-time-setup-with-blink-led-example-using-sw4stm32-and-hal-library . So without knowing your configuration of the MCU it is hard to say where the error is ...

What you should do is to set a defined inital state before toggling something  however i think this is not the problem

```
/*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```